# Cocos2d: CCMenu Item not responding to touch after resuming application

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a pause button that's a `CCMenuItem` that when I touch it, the app goes to the menu. I have the Game Scene set as a static variable on the Menu Scene so that when I resume the game I can resume my current game.

When I press the resume button, I reschedule the update on the Game Scene and replaceScene with the static Game Scene. The pause button is on a layer that the Game Scene owns.

When the game continues, the pause button is there but **doesn't respond to my touch**. I tried using onEnter to do resumeSchedulerAndActions but nothing.

I've come up with a solution which feels hacky, which is to create my menu in `onEnter` and remove it in `onExit`.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to make my menu respond to touches again?

Comment: could you add some code your pause and resume methods etc...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `popScene` of `CCDirector` to pop the menu scene from the game scene. You may not have to hack around with scheduling yourself. For this to work, the pause button would have to push the scene on the scenes stack in the first place instead of using `replaceScene`.

Answer (score 1):

You know what's hacky? Keeping a scene in a static variable. If you replace a scene, you're supposed to let go of it. Cocos2d doesn't handle multiple calls to replaceScene with the same object correctly. Either this, or overriding onEnter and not calling [super onEnter] is causing the input problems.

If you want to continue the game, either

- don't replace the scene
- push/pop the other scene
- write code to save the scene's state and restore it

Comment: I think you're absolutely right. I tried popping the scene originally and what I popped to was just a black screen. I decided to find another way instead of figuring out why the screen was black. I'm going to return to trying to figure that out. BTW, I always recommend your book as the best way to start learning cocos2d.